# Check UITextField focused on XCUITest

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any way to check a specific UITextField is focused(isFirstResponder) in XCUITest?

I'm currently using the below extension. It works but I believe there are better way to find it.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
extension XCUIElement {
    func isTextFieldFirstResponder(application: XCUIApplication) -> Bool {
        return debugDescription.containsString("Keyboard Focused")
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try typing text and then check that the text is set on the text field.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I tried but if I try to type text on `UITextField` which isn't focused, assertion occurred.

Comment: That sounds like a good failure to me :-)

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I don't want to make a failure. I just want to make sure that a textfield is not able to input till a specific condition satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking the XCUIElement's (presumably a textField, but it works with secureTextFields and textViews as well) `accessibilityElementIsFocused()` property? That's what I'm currently doing, and it does seem to work.

Comment: This isn't correct, accessibilityElementIsFocused() is on NSObject, so that will return the value of whether the XCUIElement object itself (Not the object in the app it represents) is focused, which doesn't make sense as its not in an app and something that can be focused.